# Why isn't custom SQL table column selectable/joinable in Tableau?

Tags: sql, tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a custom SQL table I make in Tableau as a stand-alone datasource

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)/100 AS MONTHLY_REWARDS,CLINIC_ID,DATE_TRUNC('month',INSERTED_AT) AS MONTH,'Total Amount' AS TYPE
FROM "MY_SCHEMA".REWARDS
WHERE CLINIC_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CLINIC_ID,MONTH,TYPE
```

I'm not modifying or casting CLINIC_ID in any way in this summary. Yet when I access this field in a workbook I can no longer use it as a User Filter, but I can for MONTH or TYPE from my summary.

[image]

And when I use just the REWARDS table as the datasource (no custom SQL), it has no trouble using it as a User Filter.

[image]

I've tried right-clicking in the Worksheet and converting to string.

[image]

When I do, it becomes a User Filter option, but using it as a filter results in no data (because it is actually an Int in the data). When I convert it back to Number (decimal), it is no longer a User Filter.

[image]

Finally, if I try to have the custom SQL with the rest of my tables and join on Clinic ID, it says the types do not match even though they come directly from the same table with no modifications.

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I start using Custom SQL as a table in these scenarios? I'd like to be able to use Clinic ID from the Custom SQL as a User Filter as well as a key to join to other tables if I want.

Comment: Why use custom SQL? Nothing in your example seems to require it?

Comment: This is the simplest case in this posting, but the actual queries I want this to leverage much more complex queries and non-trivial aggregations.

Comment: Ok, but understand that using custom queries blocks Tableau from certain query optimizations and gives up some of the flexibility. Its usually better to let Tableau generate SQL than to craft it by hand - much like a compiler and machine code. Tableau can generate complex queries. The cases where custom SQL pays off most are accessing database specific functions, using analytic/windowing queries and occasionally nested queries. In most other cases, there is a Tableau feature that will cause the SQL you want to get generated.

Comment: Related approaches that you might find useful in some cases. Raw SQL functions let  invoke a bit of SQL inside a Tableau calculated field. They are great for calling a database specific function. The raw SQL will get embedded within the SQL Tableau generates. If you do have a lot of complex transformations on the data, it is often easier/faster to have an upstream pre-processing step before analysis, say with Prep and extracts.